# Record's datetime is being set 3 hours backwards when update

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am developing a CRUD application in Spring boot and Hibernate. I have a table called `Order`. This table has two columns called `status` (integer) and   `datetime` (which of type mysql `datetime`). In my application, I regulary update that `status` column's value in one of the rows.

When I do this, something weird happens. The `status` column is updated for that record, however, the `datetime` column is also being updated, which I don't even instruct. After each update to a row, `datetime` is set to 3 hours earlier than the previous value of its.

I am developing this application in Java's Spring Boot and Spring Boot JPA MySQL. I am using JPA repositories. Here is the snipped that makes the update:

```
public String incrementOrderStatus(Long orderId) {
    Order order = orderRepository.findOne(orderId);
    OrderState nextState = order.getState().next();
    order.setState(nextState);
    orderRepository.save(order);
    return nextState.toString();
}
```

An `Order` has the following attributes:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "`order`")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private Calendar datetime;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private OrderState state;

    private String address;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String email;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private OrderSource source;

    private Float totalPrice;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    private Offer offerUsed;

    private String notes;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<MealOrderDescriptor> meals;

    public Order(CustomOrderView orderView) {
        this.name = orderView.getName();
        this.datetime = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Istanbul"));
        this.state = OrderState.PENDING;
        this.address = orderView.getAddress();
        this.phoneNumber = orderView.getPhoneNumber();
        this.source = orderView.getSource();
        this.totalPrice = orderView.getTotalPrice();
        this.notes = orderView.getNotes();
    }
}
```

In the JDBC query string I also set the timezone to my timezone, which is `serverTimezone=Europe/Istanbul`. I am using a MySQL version of 5.7.19 and JDBC version is 6.0.6, Java 1.8 and Spring Boot 1.5.9 and in an Ubuntu 16.04.3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you don't call `order.setDatetime()` before `orderRepository.save(order);`, `datetime` field contains value received by `orderRepository.findOne(orderId)`.

After that, `orderRepository.save(order);` statement tries to update `datetime` field with the value received by `orderRepository.findOne(orderId)`. If it is minus 3 hours from the previous value then it is likely a TimeZone problem.

I think, if you use `TIMESTAMP` type instead of `DATETIME` this situation will disappear. Because MySQL `DATETIME` type does not hold TimeZone information.

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.)

You can check [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html).